# Getting the percentage of values in an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

For an assignment, the user is to enter in 8 scores for home team, and 8 for the opponent team. Park of the assignment requires for the output to display the number of games the home team one and what the winning percentage is of the entire season for the home team. 
The code as follows:
Btw there is a lot more steps and methods required for the assignment, those are working perfectly, it is only this step/ method that is not.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    final int tGame = 8;
    final int oGame = 8;
    int [] texansScore;
    int [] opponentsScore;;
    texansScore = new int [8];
    opponentsScore = new int [8];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int t = 0; t < 8; t++){
        System.out.println("Score for Game " + (t + 1) + ": ");
        System.out.println(" Please enter in the Houston Texans'score: ");
        texansScore [t] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" Please enter in the opponents' score: ");
        opponentsScore [t] = sc.nextInt();


        }
        dterminePercent(texansScore, opponentsScore);
}
public static double dterminePercent ( int [] tGame, int [] oppGame){
        int [] array = new int [tGame.length];
        double won = 0;
        double winPercent = 0;
        for (int i =0; i < tGame.length; i++){
            if ( tGame [i] > oppGame [i]){
            array [i] = tGame[i];
            won = i + 1;
        }
            winPercent = won / 8.0 * 100.0;
        }
        System.out.println("The amount of games won is: " + won + "\nThe win perecntage is: " + winPercent + "%");
        return winPercent;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `won = i + 1;` to `won ++;`. You want to increment `won`, not make it one higher than the loop index `i`.